# I can't stop or kill a daemon process whatever I do. It's been days now

Tags: services, killall

That is normally great thing right? But I need to update. I've started it with

```
python openbazaard.py start -da 0.0.0.0
```

As a result, nothing from the below tried can stop it:

```
sudo python openbazaard.py stop 
OpenBazaar server stopping... pidfile /tmp/openbazaard.pid does not exist. Daemon not running?
```

It still runs after that, no matter how long I wait.

Restarting the server auto starts it, I haven't even added that. I guess because I started it as a daemon?

```
killall
```

and

```
kill -15 -1
```

temporally kill it and it auto starts right away after that. I didn't know daemons do that?

Is that normal or I'm total noob? At this point this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

You must find process pid and kill it by `kill -9 pid`.

Also you can find parent process id by this:

```
ps -o ppid= pid
```

and then kill it's parent by `kill -9 parent_id`

Comment: it gives me 2 parents?

Comment: kill both parent if you know it's not a system process

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "ps -ax" terminal command to find its pid. Then kill -9 thepid (or kill it more nicely, your choice). I think you can also get a list of pids with "lsof" but I have no idea how to do that. Hope this helps :).

Comment: this killed it but it restarted right away